# Strong params in Rails 4 (ArgumentError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

**Situation**

I want to create new Category using form.

In **new.html.erb** everything is good:

```
<%= form_for @cat do |f| %>
<%= f.label :description %>
<%= f.text_field :description %>
<br>
<%= f.label :position %>
<%= f.text_field :position %>
<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

But after "Submit" is pressed ArgumentError in CategoriesController#create is raised (Unknown key: description). http://prntscr.com/1fijdk

**categories_controller.rb**

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @categories = Category.all
  end

  def new
    @cat = Category.new
  end

  def create
    @category = Category.find(params[:category])
    redirect_to :categories
  end
end
```

**category.rb**

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :items
end
```

**schema.rb**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20130715035836) do

  create_table "categories", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "description"
    t.integer  "position"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "items", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.float    "price"
    t.text     "description"
    t.integer  "category_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

end
```

In Rails 3 everything works great, but in Rails 4 attr_accessible is not generated and I'm a little bit confused. Where is a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails 4 does not use attr_accessible but strong_parameters to allow (or not) mass assignment.
Now this is handled by the controller and not by the model, you have to specify in your controller what are the permitted attributes...

See : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters to understand how it works and at https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters

Cheers